# Need Solution for Complex SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have two tables of a voting system that iam working with.

[image] The first is called **Committee Members**

[image] And the Second is called **Committee Approval**

**Committee Approval** stores the vote details that were entered by different users. Below is a snippet of what it will hold

[image]

CommitteeApprovalStatusID foreign key column represents the ***vote*** value. Its table looks like

[image]

**CommitteeRoleID** foreign key column in Committee Members table represents a title given to users in that committee E.g janitor, chairman, member.

[image]

I want to write a query that **lists all users**, **what they voted**, and **who didn't vote** based on a **particular Licence Application**. For Example, For a particular Licence **Application 10342** the format would be like

**UserID    |    Role     |   Status    |   What he voted    |**

Examples of Statements i tried was

> SELECT * FROM CommitteeMembers  LEFT OUTER JOIN  CommitteeApproval  ON
>   CommitteeMembers.UserID = CommitteeApproval.UserID
>   WHERE CommitteeApproval.LicenceApplicationID = 10682

*But that only brings null values from the columns of the CommitteeApproval table*

I have tried various statements but none has worked so far. Anyone know an effective solution to achieve this??

Comment: Can you post the SQL you have tried?

Comment: It would be incredibly helpful to post DDL and DML statements instead of screenshots or even create a sql fiddle with the details

Comment: SQL fiddle would be the best option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can OUTER JOIN and evaluate for the presence of the record...if the record isn't even there it means the member didn't vote.  The role and MemberStatus should be inner joined because they'll always exist for every member.

```
SELECT
    committeeMembers.UserID,
    committeeMemberStatus.committeeMemberStatus AS [MemberStatus],
    committeeRoles.CommitteeRoleName AS [Role],

    Case 
        When committeeApproval.CommitteeApprovalStatusID IS NULL Then 'No Vote'
        Else committeeApprovalStatuses.CommitteeApprovalStatusName
    End AS [ApprovalStatus],

FROM CommitteeMembers committeeMembers
    INNER JOIN CommitteeMemberStatus committeeMemberStatus ON committeeMemberStatus.CommitteeMemberStatusID = committeeMembers.CommitteeMemberStatusID
    INNER JOIN CommitteeRoles committeeRoles ON committeeRoles.CommitteeRoleID = committeeMembers.CommitteeRoleID

    LEFT OUTER JOIN CommitteeApproval committeeApproval ON committeeApproval.UserID = committeeMembers.UserID
```

Comment: Just a design consideration, but I would also note that because a committee member is the one voting, they should be referenced in the committee approval table and not the 'UserID'.  The way it's structured implies that a User is voting, but you may very well have other user types (e.g. site user, guest user, non-committee member) that don't actually vote, though the table design allows that.